# How use davmails with Office365 modern authentication

Tags: authentication, outlook, office365

i want to use Davmail to transfer mails from Outlook shared mailbox to ThePhish (: https://github.com/emalderson/ThePhish) and i saw this site: https://davmail.sourceforge.net/ that explain how do this but it didn't work i already created my own application in Azure Active directory to get my client ID and tenant ID and secret.

So i tried to put the client ID and tenant ID in Davmail.properties like this [pictures of my davmail.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aHP8.png), [davmail.properties following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWN1d.png), [davmail.properties following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqpVk.png), [davmail.properties following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFk6s.png).
I don't understand where i have to put the secret value and ID. When i try to list mails in ThePhish i have this error [error ThePhish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpYG.png) nothing else when i try to inspect the page.